# how to work with datetime asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

```
Error   Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.DateTime?' to 'System.DateTime'
```

And the code is the following:

```
 if (DateTime.Now.Subtract(ltime.lasttime1 )> 4)
            return false;
```

Where ltime is a table in database, and lasttime1 's type  is `datetime`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that `lasttime1` is [nullable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx). So you need to obtain it's actual value:

```
if (DateTime.Now.Subtract(ltime.lasttime1.Value )> 4)
        return false;
```

The above assumes that it will always turn out not to be null. You may have to test [`HasValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sksw8094.aspx) first and go down a different code path if you need to cope with `NULL`s.

Answer (score 2):

ltime.lasttime1 must be Nullable (Shorthand DateTime?). Use

```
lftime.lasttime1.Value
```

Remember to check if the lftime.lasttime1 is null:

```
lftime.lasttime1.HasValue
```